# Checkboxes on a dynamically generated sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am building a spreadsheet of 20 different sensors for water leaks being updated daily with hourly data. One of the sheets is a daily overview of various analyses done on each of the sensor data.

In the dynamically generated "Daily Overview" I want to put three checkboxes at the end of each row, to be clicked:

1. if a plumber was called
2. if a leak was found
3. if the leak was fixed

(In the "Daily Overview", `A1` is today's date, and all the data is collected through a `VLOOKUP`. So, the checkbox at `I2` should disappear if the date changes, but return if the I change the `A1` date again.)

In each of the sensor pages, there are also three checkboxes at the end of every day's data, in columns `AF`, `AG`, and `AH`.

I'm looking for a formulaic way to click on one of the boxes in the "Daily Overview" to make a change in the correct box on the sensor page.

In effect, I want the opposite of this: `=VLOOKUP(A1,'32033'!A2:AE,32)` in the checkbox area to put this data on another sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h1JB_Z5dEXUAoCxJlbIjuu3mkcK4CwCotYSZzIYx2Y0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You'll need a script to handle edits to the overview

Answer (score 0):

it would be like this (in `32033` sheet):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A2:A)=MATCH('Daily Overview'!A1, A1:A, 0), 
 INDIRECT("Daily Overview!I"&MATCH("32033", 'Daily Overview'!A1:A, 0)&
                     ":"&"K"&MATCH("32033", 'Daily Overview'!A1:A, 0))))
```

[image: 0]

---

also by adding this script:

```
function sheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

you could do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A2:A)=MATCH('Daily Overview'!A1, A1:A, 0), 
 INDIRECT("Daily Overview!I"&MATCH(sheetName(), 'Daily Overview'!A1:A, 0)&
                     ":"&"K"&MATCH(sheetName(), 'Daily Overview'!A1:A, 0))))
```

---

note: formula will output `TRUE` / `FALSE` statuses so select AF2:AH and convert it to checkboxes (Insert > Checkbox)

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't actually store it on the `32033` sheet. If you change the date on the `Daily Overview`, it doesn't reset the checkboxes and it changes the values on the `32033` sheet. Perhaps I must do this programmatically.

Comment: @EzraButler well, of course, it won't store it. formulas can't store values. for that you will need a scripted solution - that's the only way how to store values.

Comment: this is why I compared it to something like `=VLOOKUP(A1,'32033'!A2:AE,32)`. Because when `A1` is changed, it changes all the cells based on the data sheets. I want `Daily Overview` to pull the data from `32033`, but I also want it be to be the place where the user updates the data. Does that make sense?